# Where is the code in the Microsoft Calculator where two numbers are added together?

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

I've downloaded the [Microsoft Calculator source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator) to try to learn from some good code.

Where in the code does it add two numbers together? I've even searched through the unit tests, but I can't find this basic operation.

Comment: NOTE: Microsoft Calculator in Standard mode ignores order of operations.

Comment: @user4581301 no, it **does respect the order of operations** in modes other than standard (where it follows the same rule as non-scientific pocket calculators where each step is done separately without an operation stack). [Is there a way to fix windows calculator order of operations?](https://superuser.com/q/578753/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a simple grep search of the repository:

```
find -name "*.cpp" | xargs -i grep add {} /dev/null
```

I've determined it's a function called `addnum` located at: `src/CalcManager/Ratpack/num.cpp`

Comment: `grep -rI add --include=*.cpp .` would be faster and shorter